# cyclic subgroup generated by $a^m$ is the same as the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^d$

Tags: group-theory

> Let G = $<a>$ be a cyclic group of order n. Prove that the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^m$ is the same as the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^d$, where d = (m, n)

The book said it suffices to show that $a^d$ is a power of $a^m$. 
I proved it using d = mu + nv. But I don't know why it suffices

Comment: Because for any cylic groups:  If $<a>$ is the group generated by $a$ and $a^k$ is the group generated by $<a^k>$ then $<a^k> \subset <a>$ (because $(a^k)^n \in <a^k> \implies (a^k)^n = a^{kn} \in <a>$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a^d$ is a power of $a^m$, then $a^d\in \langle a^m\rangle$, and hence $\langle a^d \rangle \subseteq \langle a^m \rangle$.

On the other hand, $a^m$ is clearly a power of $a^d$, so by a similar argument   $\langle a^m \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle$.